# Copy variables to another R dataset and rename variables

Tags: r

I have two datasets with different names but with some variables having the same name but different content. Now I'd like to copy the coincident variables to another dataset and in the process rename one of the coincident variables. Is this possible?

**Example:**

```
DataSet1.RData has

....
matrix1
matrix2
....

DataSet2.RData has

....
matrix1
matrix2
....
```

I'd like to create a third DataSet (`DataSet3`) with:

```
matrix1
matrix2
matrix3 (former matrix1 of DataSet2.RData)
matrix4 (former matrix2 of DataSet2.RData)
```

Alternatively, I'd be happy just copying and renaming the specified variables from one DataSet to the other. Thanks

Comment: [Have you triead anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Barranka, yes I've search the web but nothing relevant come up.

Comment: So by "dataset" you mean R objects that have been saved to an RData file via `save()`? And right now you're using `load()` but the objects objects are getting re-written each time? Do you want to explicitly name all the objects during load? Or do you want to just avoid name collisions? Are you only using the global environment or are you loading objects into custom environments?

Comment: I'm using Rstudio and it uses this term "Import Dataset". Yes, objects are being re-written each time. I'm OK by just not replacing the variables and have them renamed instead. I'm using the global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a wrapper to `load` to rename objects that conflict with the existing workspace. Fopr example

```
safeload<-function(file, env=parent.frame()) {
    tmp<-new.env()
    load.names <- load(file, tmp)
    exist.names <- ls(envir=env)
    new.names <- make.names(c(exist.names, load.names), unique=TRUE)[-seq_along(exist.names)]
    Map(assign, new.names, mget(load.names, tmp), MoreArgs=list(envir=env))
    attr(new.names, "orig.names) <- load.names
    invisible(new.names)
}
```

Then if you try

```
m1 <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
m2 <- matrix(5:8, ncol=2)
save(m1,m2, file="t1.RData")

m1 <- matrix(11:14, ncol=2)
m2 <- matrix(15:18, ncol=2)
save(m1,m2, file="t2.RData")
```

You will see the current values of `m1` and `m2` are

```
m1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   11   13
# [2,]   12   14

m2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   15   17
# [2,]   16   18
```

then if we run

```
safeload("t1.RData")
```

this would try to re-load `m1` and `m2, but since those exist, we use`make.name()`to create unique names for those values. It renames the`m1`to`m1.1`. So now we have

```
m1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   11   13
# [2,]   12   14

m1.1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

This function should never over-write values, it will always append something to make the name unique. So of you keep running `safeload` on the same RData file, then it will keep creating new variables. The function will invisibly return the final names of the objects that it just loaded (with the original names from the RData file as an attribute named "orig.names")

If you only want to "merge" those two RData files, something like

```
newds<-new.env()
safeload("t1.RData", newds)
safeload("t2.RData", newds)
save(list=ls(envir=newsd), envir=newds, file="t3.RData")
```

This way those variables will never actually be loaded into the global environment.